# APIs to render custom WMTS source

Tags: android, api, ios, wmts

We have a custom WMTS source which we want to show on Android and iOS. What would be my options to do this using native APIs (so no Leaflet or OpenLayers)?

An ideal API not only shows the maps but can also handle the interaction with a map (panning, pinch zoom, detecting clicks etc.). It should also offer us a way to draw figures, images and text on top of the map.

I've tried searching for it online and so far I have come up with Google Maps and ArcGIS. Does anyone know any other native APIs, preferably open source or with a flexible license.

Comment: Do you want the same API on both Android & iOS?

Comment: Not necessarily, I am looking for any API which can show a custom WMTS source. Having the same API on Android and iOS could make it easier because I would only need to learn one API however it is not a requirement.

Comment: I'll suggest that you have a look at the Mapbox APIs. They are quite similar for both Android & iOS

Answer (score 1):

Here I shared my knowledge about this WMTS Layer question. Since there are so many 3rd party of those WMTS layer, it is better to test first for specific WMTS source with certain API.

I am not really sure how did you test the WMTS Layer with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS, but here is a good code snippet sample to check-out (both .h & .m file on GitHub):

https://github.com/NoashX/iOS_WMTS/blob/master/ViewController.h
https://github.com/NoashX/iOS_WMTS/blob/master/ViewController.m

Also, here is the API reference about [AGSWMSLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_w_m_s_layer.html) Class. This class searches for a spatial reference in the root layer. If it cannot find one there it searches each layer contained in the root layer. If no spatial reference is found the layer fails.

Hope this can help you to test.

Best Regards,